# How to check if jqgrid row is expanded or collapsed if I have the rowId?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

This will be short: How to check if jqgrid row is expanded or collapsed if I have the rowId?

I've searched in google, jqgrid wiki, and here in stackoverflow with no success.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you use Subgrid, Subgrid as Grid, Treegrid or Data grouping? Which version of jqGrid you use? Which fork of jqGrid you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old version of jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Comment: I am using 4.6.0 and subGrid:, subGridOptions: subGridRowExpanded:. In subGridRowExpanded handler I am creating a complete grid in the expanded area.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Subgrid as Grid scenario then the grid have "subgrid" column with "+" or "-" symbol for expending/collapsing of subgrid. The `<td>` element in the column contains always `ui-sgcollapsed` class and it have additional class `sgcollapsed` or `sgexpanded`. Initial grid contains the column "subgrid" where all `<td>` elements have both `ui-sgcollapsed` and `sgcollapsed` classes. It means that the rows are collapsed and the user can see "+" icon. After the user clicks on some the "+" icons the subgrid will be created, the "+" icon will be replaced to "-" icon and the `sgcollapsed` class in of `td.ui-sgcollapsed` will be replaced to `sgexpanded`.

In other words you can do something like the following: You can get `<tr>` element (the row) by using `getGridRowById` or `getInd` method or just by usage of `$("#" + rowid)`. After that you can find the `<td>` with "+" or "-" icon by usage of `.find(">td.ui-sgcollapsed")` on the `<tr>` element. Finally you can use `jQuery.hasClass` function to test for `sgcollapsed` or `sgexpanded` class to detect whether the subgrid is expended in the row or it's collapsed.